# Android UDP receive drops packets intermittently

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp, video-streaming

I have a Nexus 5X that is having intermittent receive problems. I have been able to run the code on an Asus tablet, two Samsung tablets, and a Kindle Fire with no issues. The code is based on this repository:
https://github.com/moonlight-stream/moonlight-common/blob/master/src/com/limelight/nvstream/av/video/VideoStream.java

Here is the pertinent code:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiLock = wifiMgr.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "Player");
wifiLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
wifiLock.acquire();

rtp = new DatagramSocket(RTP_PORT);
rtp.setReceiveBufferSize(256*1024);

// Receive thread
Thread t = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!isInterrupted())
    {
        try {
            // Pull the next buffer in the ring and reset it
            buffer = ring[ringIndex].getBuffer();

            // Read the video data off the network
            packet.setData(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            rtp.receive(packet);

            // Do processing here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
};
threads.add(t);
t.setName("Video - Receive");
t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY - 1);
t.start();
```

I am as sure as I can be that the UDP stream is properly being sent to the device. Most of the packets are received correctly. However, I've noticed in a method trace that the

```
rtp.receive(packet);
```

can block for 100s-1000s of milliseconds. When running on a different device in the exact same architecture, I see essentially 100% packet success and a maximum block of maybe 60ms.

I have tried this on 2.4G, and 5G, on multiple routers. The problem follows the device.

The packets being sent are UDP directly to the device. There are no IP conflicts on the network.

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong? Thank you very much!

EDIT: I should note the CPU usage is around 2%, and the memory usage is around 10MB

EDIT 2: I created a bare application to simply investigate this issue. I see the same results. I'll see 30,000+ consecutive packets on several devices without a single drop. I'll drop a range of packets every couple seconds on a Nexus 5X. I've had someone remotely run this test application on their Nexus 5X, and they reported that no packets were dropped. All signs are pointing to a driver / radio issue as far as I know...

```
package com.udp_receiver_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;
    Thread t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "Player");
        wifiLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
        wifiLock.acquire();

        // Use sustained performance mode on N+ to ensure consistent
        // CPU availability
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            getWindow().setSustainedPerformanceMode(true);
        }


        startListenThread();
    }

    private void startListenThread()
    {
        t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                DatagramSocket socket;

                int nextSequenceNumber = 0;

                ByteBuffer byteBuffer;

                int BufferSize = 1292;
                int NumRingElements = 784;
                long correctPacketCounter = 0;

                byte ring[][] = new byte[NumRingElements][1292];

                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
                    socket.setReceiveBufferSize(256 * 1024);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                byte[] buffer;
                int ringCounter = 0;
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1], 1);
                //short rtpSequenceNumber;
                int sequenceNumber;

                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        buffer = ring[ringCounter];

                        packet.setData(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);

                        if (packet.getLength() > 20) {

                            // Read the RTP sequence number field (big endian)
                            byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
                            byteBuffer.position(16);
                            sequenceNumber = (byteBuffer.getInt() >> 8) & 0xFFFFFF;

                            if (sequenceNumber != nextSequenceNumber) {
                                Log.d("TAG", "Not next sequence number - Got:" + sequenceNumber + " Expected:" + nextSequenceNumber);
                            } else {

                                if (((++correctPacketCounter) % 100) == 0)
                                {
                                    Log.d("TAG", "Correct packets = " + correctPacketCounter);
                                }

                            }

                            nextSequenceNumber = (sequenceNumber + 256) % 65535;
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Message too short");
                        }

                        ringCounter = (ringCounter + 1) % NumRingElements;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.setName("Receiver");
        t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY - 1);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        wifiLock.release();
        if (t.isAlive()) {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify with a network sniffer that the packets are actually arriving on the device in a timely manner? `receive()` should not block unless it is actually waiting for a new packet to arrive.  Have you considered moving your processing code to another thread so your receive thread is not blocked from reading in a timely manner?  If you don't read the packets as fast as they are being sent, you might get packets dropped over time.

Comment: I'm doing this over wifi, so I think a packet sniffer would not be very reliable. I've gone so far as to have the stream sent to a separate device that had no issues, turn that off, and change my faulty device to a static IP. I'm not sure how much more certain I can get that the packets are being sent since I'm now seeing 6 devices work flawlessly and one device constatly have issues.
The processing loop takes 1's of milliseconds and I'm sending approximately 300 packets/second.
I have made a barebones app that has no processing - same behavior. I'll post the code to that in a moment.